# Exception is only thrown in debug+breakpoint

Tags: java, network-programming

So I've got a thread to Receive Data from a client. There is a ObjectInputReader to read this Data. If the ObjectInputReader couldn't be initialized in my try-catch, what happens if the client disconnected without notifying the server, the try-catch should call an exception.

So I've got my "disconnect Client" handling in the Catch-Statement. But it never happens.

But if I'm running the Server on debug AND set a Breakpoint in the Catch-Statement then the exception occurs and everything is handled like I want it. But only with the Breakpoint, never without (debug or release).

I'm using eclipse, i think newest version.

Did someone ever happen to have this "bug"? Or am I doing something wrong?

```
private static Runnable receive = new Runnable(){

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ObjectInputStream ois;

        while(true)
        {
            for(int i = 0; i < listSockets.size();i++){
                try {
                    ois = new ObjectInputStream(listSockets.get(i).getInputStream());
                    int receiveState = (Integer)ois.readObject();

                    DataPackage dp = (DataPackage)ois.readObject();

                    listData.set(i,dp);

                    if(receiveState == 1){ //client disconnected by user
                        disconnectClient(i);
                        i--;
                    }

                    ois.close();
                } catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
                    disconnectClient(i);
                    i--;
                }

            }
        }
    }


};
```

Comment: What happens when you don't have the breakpoint in, does the loop, loop forever?

Comment: Well there are some issues i just figured out:

The while(true) starts the for-loop and checks the listSockets.size() which is 0. At this point, a Client connects and the size increases. But the while-loop and the check don't get notified that the size increased so there is a infinity loop between these commands. If i check the size with an if statement and sysout the size before the for, everything works.

Comment: Are you still seeing different behaviour between when you have your breakpoint and when you don't ?

Comment: In general, different behavior when you just take a breakpoint is a symptom of a bug involving asynchronous behavior. Maybe the thread running this Runnable needs to wait for another thread to do something to increase listSockets.size().

Comment: Consider controlling further use of `ois` by the check of `receiveState`. (`ois` deserves a "try with resources".)

Answer (score 0):

Allways keep in mind that debugging might influence your program. Especially when you inspect variables the jvm causes lot's of toString() methods to be called. If one toString() method changes the state of one of your objects, the result will change. Try something like

```
} catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
      System.out.println("I am here");
      disconnectClient(i);
      i--;
}
```

to see if the program really jumps into the catch block or the disconnectClient method has a flaw. If you add a few more System.out. You might see were the Programm stops.

Comment: With this "I am here" syso nothing happend when running in release or debugging. But when running with a breakpoint the exception is thrown. So it's like without this statement.

Comment: well either their is an asynchronous bug in your code (as Patricia Shanahan mentioned in her comment) or you found a java bug. You could try this code on another java version to be sure (though you might need to change some of your code if you want to run it in java 6 or 5)